# How to save and retrieve Latitude and Longitude from a Location object in Room Database

Tags: android, android-room, android-location

I'm using AndroidX Room component for a small offline database in my app. I want to be able to save the Location (latitude and longitude) of the user to the database and use it later.
How to do it and what is the best practices ?

I've never done that before and couldn't find any help on the web.

This is how I'm actually doing it (and obviously the wrong way) :

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "session_location")
var sessionLocation: Location
```

I get an error  `Cannot figure out how to save this field into database`

Comment: You could store Lat and Long as separate strings

Comment: Use TypeConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your `Location` class? Is it `android.location.Location` or is it some data class that you defined?

In any case I would have used `@Embedded` POJO classes instead of `TypeConverters` as others recommend.

If `Location` is a class that you already defined then just add `@Embedded` annotation on top of your sessionLocation

```
@Embedded
@ColumnInfo(name = "session_location")
var sessionLocation: Location
```

Else if `Location` is the `android.location.Location` then you don't need to store all the information in that class. You must need basic ones which are `lat & long`.

I would have just created a class `Location` and store those basic information and add it as `@Embedded`. Something like below

```
class Location {
    var latitude: Double = 0
    var longitude: Double = 0
}

class User {
    @Embedded
    @ColumnInfo(name = "session_location")
    var sessionLocation: Location
}
```

As others suggested `TypeConverter` is a solution but there is no need serialize/deserialize a `POJO` when you can simply save it directly.

Comment: My Location class is indeed the `android.location.Location` class.
Thanks for your response, but since I'm working on a training project I'm gonna go with the type converter because I'm not familiar with it.
I'll keep your solution in mind just in case.

Comment: That would be a way but you'll have to define your custom Location class, by the way your suggestion is useful

Answer (score 1):

You should define your own converter for types that are not supported by Room. Basically SQLite supports only primitive types as column fields.
For each complex data type you have to define a custom converter, since Room doesn't know how to serialize your complex type in database columns.
To do so, you need to create a converter which is responsible to convert your complex structured type in primitive fields:

**E.g. (from android documentation)**

```kotlin
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time?.toLong()
    }
}
```

In your case the simpliest way would be using **GSON** to serialize your object as a JSON string (when you are writing to your database - Room supports string), then parsing the string from the database to your `Location` object when you read from the database

In your case I would do something like:

```kotlin
class LocationConverter {
   @TypeConverter
    fun toLocation(locationString: String?): Location? {
        return try {
            Gson().fromJson(locationString, Location::class.java)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toLocationString(location: Location?): String? {
        return Gson().toJson(location)
    }
}
```

Once your done with the converter, annotate your database with the `LocationConverter` you've just defined and you're done!

```kotlin
@TypeConverters(LocationConverter::class)
abstract class YourDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, I've read a bit about the type converter but had no clue about GSON, which is much better than just storing long & lat who seem a bit barbarian. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Hope it helps, best wishes!

Comment: I tried storing Location objects with GSON but unfortunately it does not work. Only one value is saved. Is the custom TypeConverter necessary?

Comment: @Flyview, in a word: yes. SQLite can store complex data such as location, you have to define your own type converter to transform your structured type into a supported one. More info here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html